# Wordpress Search - display taxonomy terms in results

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

I have a custom post type of Hotel. Hotels can be can be categorised with the taxonomy Resort.

On my search page I need to be able to list hotels **and** taxonomy terms in the results, as separate results. eg:

```
Resort Name
Hotel Name
Hotel Name
Hotel Name
```

Resorts should come first, followed by hotels and anything else. As far as I know taxonomy terms are not shown by default in WordPress search.

In my functions.php I'm currently limiting the search to specific post types:

```
function filter_search($query) {
// Don't run in admin area
if(!is_admin()) {
    // Limit search to posts
    if($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('hotel', 'post', 'activities', 'page'));
    }

    // Return query
    return $query;
  }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');
```

Then in my search.php I am grouping the results by post type:

```
<?php $types = array('hotel', 'post', 'activities', 'page');
foreach( $types as $type ){

echo '<div class="results"> '; ?>

<?php while( have_posts() ){
  the_post();
  if( $type == get_post_type() ){ ?>

    <div class="result">
      <div class="result-inner">
        <h2>
          <?php if ( $type ==  "hotel"  ) { ?>
            Hotel: 
          <?php } elseif ( $type == "activities" ) { ?>
            Activity: 
          <?php } elseif ( $type == "post" ) { ?>
            Blog Post: 
          <?php } elseif ( $type == "page" ) { ?>
            Page: 
          <?php } else { ?>
            Page: 
          <?php } ?>

          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <p class="blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="button">View Page</a></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    <?php }
} 
rewind_posts();
echo '</div> ';
} ?>
```

What I'm struggling with is how to tell WordPress to show the taxonomy term (Resort) in the results as it's own result. Can anybody help?

UPDATE: I'm happy to preserve the default WordPress search order. The results don't have to be *grouped* by taxonomy term. I just need to be able to spit out the term *as a result itself*, with a link to the term (and be counted in the search count query). So if a search matches a taxonomy term that should come first, followed by the other results in whatever order.

Comment: This is a beautiful occurrence when a man can formulate his question the right way. This is a rare chance to see it. Read this with Mr. Attenborough voice.

I'm pretty sure English is not his mother tongue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just need to be able to spit out the term as a *result itself*, with
>   a link to the term (and be counted in the search count query). So if a
>   search matches a taxonomy term that should come first, followed by the
>   other results in whatever order.

`WP_Query::$posts` are `WP_Post` objects and can't include (or be mixed with) term/`WP_Term` objects.

However, there's a way to achieve what you want — use `get_terms()` to search for the taxonomy terms and modify the `WP_Query`'s `posts_per_page` and `offset` parameters to make the matched terms *as if* they're part of the actual search results (which are posts).

Note though, for now, `get_terms()`/`WP_Term_Query` supports single search keywords only — i.e. `foo, bar` is treated as one keyword — in `WP_Query`, that would be two keywords (`foo` and `bar`).

### The Code/Steps

#### In `functions.php`:

Add this:

```php
function wpse342309_search_terms( $query, $taxonomy ) {
    $per_page = absint( $query->get( 'posts_per_page' ) );
    if ( ! $per_page ) {
        $per_page = max( 10, get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );
    }

    $paged = max( 1, $query->get( 'paged' ) );
    $offset = absint( ( $paged - 1 ) * $per_page );
    $args = [
        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
//      'hide_empty' => '0',
        'search'     => $query->get( 's' ),
        'number'     => $per_page,
        'offset'     => $offset,
    ];

    $query->terms = [];
    $terms = get_terms( $args );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
        $query->terms = $terms;
    }

    $args['offset'] = 0; // always 0
    $args['fields'] = 'count';
    $query->found_terms = get_terms( $args );

    $query->term_count = count( $query->terms );
    $query->terms_per_page = $per_page; // for WP_Query::$max_num_pages
    $query->is_all_terms = ( (int) $per_page === $query->term_count );

    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', max( 1, $per_page - $query->term_count ) );
    $query->set( 'offset', $query->term_count ? 0 :
        max( 0, $offset - $query->found_terms ) );
}
```

In the `filter_search()`, add `wpse342309_search_terms( $query, 'resort' );` after this line:

```php
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'hotel', 'post', 'activities', 'page' ) );
```

#### In `search.php`, for the main WordPress query:

```php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :

    $total = $wp_query->found_posts + $wp_query->found_terms;
    $wp_query->max_num_pages = ceil( $total / $wp_query->terms_per_page );

    echo '<div class="results">';

    // Display terms matching the search query.
    if ( ! empty( $wp_query->terms ) ) {
        global $term; // for use in the template part (below)
        foreach ( $wp_query->terms as $term ) {
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search-term' );
        }
    }

    // Display posts matching the search query.
    if ( ! $wp_query->is_all_terms ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search-post' );
        }
    }

    echo '</div><!-- .results -->';

    // Display pagination.
    //the_posts_pagination();
    echo paginate_links( [
        'total'   => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    ] );

else :
    echo '<h1>No Posts Found</h1>';

endif; // end have_posts()
?>
```

#### In `search.php`, for a *custom* WordPress query:

You should always *manually* call `wpse342309_search_terms()`.

```php
<?php
$my_query = new WP_Query( [
    's' => 'foo',
    // ... your args here ...
] );

// Manually apply the terms search.
wpse342309_search_terms( $my_query, 'resort' );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

    $total = $my_query->found_posts + $my_query->found_terms;
    $my_query->max_num_pages = ceil( $total / $my_query->terms_per_page );

    echo '<div class="results">';

    // Display terms matching the search query.
    if ( ! empty( $my_query->terms ) ) {
        global $term; // for use in the template part (below)
        foreach ( $my_query->terms as $term ) {
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search-term' );
        }
    }

    // Display posts matching the search query.
    if ( ! $my_query->is_all_terms ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search-post' );
        }
    }

    echo '</div><!-- .results -->';

    // Display pagination.
    echo paginate_links( [
        'total'   => $my_query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    ] );

else :
    echo '<h1>No Posts Found</h1>';

endif; // end have_posts()
?>
```

#### Template Part 1: `template-parts/content-search-term.php`

```php
<?php global $term;
$term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'resort' ); ?>

<div class="result">
    <div class="result-inner">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $term->name ); ?></a></h2>

        <p class="blog-more"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $term_link ); ?>" class="button">View Page</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Template Part 2: `template-parts/content-search-post.php`

```php
<?php $type = get_post_type(); ?>

<div class="result">
    <div class="result-inner">
        <h2>
            <?php if ( $type ==  "hotel"  ) { ?>
                Hotel:
            <?php } elseif ( $type == "activities" ) { ?>
                Activity:
            <?php } elseif ( $type == "post" ) { ?>
                Blog Post:
            <?php } elseif ( $type == "page" ) { ?>
                Page:
            <?php } else { ?>
                Page:
            <?php } ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <p class="blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View Page</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @sally-cj. I think it's almost there but this is giving me a server error now. I think it might be infinite looping. If I remove the `foreach ( $types as $type ) {` from the content-search.php it lists out the same resort name multiple times (the correct amount of times - there should be 7 results and it lists the same resort 7 times).

Comment: Check the updated answer. (and remove the `template-parts/content-search.php` file)

Comment: Thank you so much @sally-cj, this fixed it! The results are now as they should be. The only thing that's a bit off is the result count which doesn't seem to include any resort results. I'm using this outside of the loop: `<?php 
$allsearch = new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1"); 
$key = wp_specialchars($s, 1); 
$count = $allsearch->post_count; 
echo $count . ' '; _e('pages found'); wp_reset_query(); ?>`

Comment: I've updated all the code, so be sure to update yours. (check the answer starting from the "The Code/Steps" line) Let me know if you have questions regarding the updated code.

Comment: If you do not actually want to automatically apply the terms search to the main WordPress (search) query, comment out or just remove the `wpse342309_search_terms( $query, 'resort' );` you added to `filter_search()`.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help. I'm still getting incorrect search counts though. I wonder if there's something else going on in my theme rather than your code not working correctly. Is there somewhere I could send you login details to take a peek if you have time?

Comment: Have you tried the exact code for the custom WordPress query? The one with `$my_query = new WP_Query( [ 's' => 'foo' ] );`. And actually, looking at the code in your previous comment, `$allsearch->post_count` is not the number of pages; it's `$allsearch->max_num_pages`.

Comment: All working now! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: No problem. :) And, can you accept the answer now? So that people see the question has an accepted answer..

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to have a display like this:

```
Hotels: Resort 1 <- "Resort 1" is a term in the "resort" taxonomy
  Sample Hotel
  Sample Hotel 2
  Sample Hotel 4 <- This post is assigned to both "Resort 1" and "Resort 2"

Hotels: Resort 2 <- "Resort 2" is a term in the "resort" taxonomy
  Sample Hotel 3
  Sample Hotel 4 <- This post is assigned to both "Resort 1" and "Resort 2"

Blog Posts
  Sample Post
  Sample Post 2

Activities
  Sample Activity
  Sample Activity 2

Pages
  Sample Page
```

Then this can give you that, where we first group the posts by their post type or by the "resort" term name for "hotel" posts: (this is inside `search.php`)

```php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="results">

        <?php
        $_posts = $wp_query->posts;
        $posts_arr = [];
        $resorts = [];

        foreach ( $_posts as $i => $p ) {
            // Group "hotel" posts by the "resort" term name.
            if ( 'hotel' === $p->post_type ) {
                $terms = get_the_terms( $p, 'resort' );
                if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        if ( ! isset( $resorts[ $term->name ] ) ) {
                            $resorts[ $term->name ] = [];
                        }
                        $resorts[ $term->name ][] =& $_posts[ $i ];
                    }
                }
            // Group other posts by their type.
            } else {
                if ( ! isset( $posts_arr[ $p->post_type ] ) ) {
                    $posts_arr[ $p->post_type ] = [];
                }
                $posts_arr[ $p->post_type ][] =& $_posts[ $i ];
            }
        }
        $posts_arr['hotel'] = ! empty( $resorts );

        // List of post_type => Heading.
        $types = [
            'hotel'      => 'Hotels',
            'post'       => 'Blog Posts',
            'activities' => 'Activities',
            'page'       => 'Pages',
        ];

        foreach ( $types as $type => $heading ) {
            if ( ! isset( $posts_arr[ $type ] ) ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Display "hotel" posts.
            if ( 'hotel' === $type ) {
                foreach ( $resorts as $name => $ps ) {
                    echo '<h2>Hotels: ' . $name . '</h2>';
                    foreach ( $ps as $post ) {
                        setup_postdata( $post );
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
                    }
                }
            // Display posts in other post types.
            } else {
                echo '<h2>' . $heading . '</h2>';
                foreach ( $posts_arr[ $type ] as $post ) {
                    setup_postdata( $post );
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
                }
            }
        }

        unset( $_posts, $posts_arr, $resorts );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .results -->

<?php endif; // end have_posts() ?>
```

And the template part (`content-search.php` inside `wp-content/themes/your-theme/template-parts`):

```php
<div <?php post_class( 'result' ); ?>>
    <div class="result-inner">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        <p class="blog-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button">View Page</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @sally-cj. This is nice but I need pagination as kuchenundkakao suggests. And I want the term to be counted as a result itself. I have updated my question.

Comment: Perhaps my other answer can help?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group your search results by a custom taxonomy, you can either group your posts AFTER the query like Sally CJ proposed, but this would only work correctly if you have all of your search results on one page.

To order search results AND use pagination, you have to alter your MySQL Query, so that's what we're going to do.

Step 1:
Add a filter to "posts_clauses" within the pre_get_posts action to change the generated Query:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','setup_my_query_interception');

function setup_my_query_interception($query){
    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query()){
     add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'order_by_taxonomy_intercept_query_clauses', 20, 1 );
  }
}
```

Step 2: In the order_by_taxonomy_intercept_query_clauses function, you enhance the Query:

```
function order_by_taxonomy_intercept_query_clauses($pieces){
        global $wpdb;
        //First we add the taxonomy and term tables to our joins...
        $pieces['join'].=" LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships trt ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = trt.object_id) LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ttt ON (trt.term_taxonomy_id = ttt.term_taxonomy_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms termts ON (termts.term_id = ttt.term_id)";
        //Now we add a WHERE condition that we only want Resort Terms
        $pieces['where'].=" AND ttt.taxonomy = 'resort'"; //change this, if your taxonomy type is named different
        //At last, we tell the orderby to FIRST order by the term title, after that use the wanted orderby
        $pieces['orderby']="termts.name ASC, ".$pieces['orderby'];
        //Remove the filter so it only runs once in our main query
        remove_filter('posts_clauses', 'order_by_taxonomy_intercept_query_clauses');
        return $pieces;
}
```

Step 3: Your search results will now be ordered by resorts first. If you want to echo the Resort name BEFORE the results, you will have to do something like this in your search.php or index.php:

before the loop:

```
if(is_search()){
    global $activetax;
    $activetax = "";
    echo '<div class="mywrapper">
}
```

in the loop:

```
if(is_search()){
$resorts = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(),'resort');
if(is_array($resorts)){
    if(!($activetax==$resorts[0]->name)){
            $activetax = $resorts[0]->name;
            ?>
            </div>
            <h2 id="tax_id_<?php echo $resorts[0]->term_id; ?>" class="resort-header"><?php echo $activetax; ?></h2>
            <div class="mywrapper">
            <?php
    }
}
}
get_template_part('content');
```

after the loop:

```
if(is_search()){
 echo "</div>";
}
```

Did not test it, but it should work.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you @kuchenundkakao. This feels really close. I have updated my question slightly as I need the term to be counted as a result itself, rather than a heading. The results don't seem to include results from any other post types using this code either. I need it to include activities, hotels, pages and posts if possible.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting method is explained by Chandan Kumar on [his blog post](http://atiblog.com/custom-search-results/) (Jan 2019) that combines multiple queries, cleans them up, and then presents combined results:

> 1. Remove the old query in the search.php file.
> 2. Get all the category, tag and custom taxonomy in array format. And loop every array and find matching name in these arrays. Then store
>      the ids of the matched name in a separate array.
> 3. Using wp_query, query all the posts (by tax query )with these matched ids. Then store the resulting post_ids in an array.
> 4. Now perform a default search_query and store all the ids in an array.
> 5. Now we have got two arrays of  ids which is the result.
> 6. Combine these two and remove duplicates.
> 7. Now we will perform a last query and show all the posts (by post__in parameter of wp_query).

There is no license mentioned on his code, but he seems to be sharing it publicly:

```
<div class="page-description"><?php echo get_search_query(); ?></div>
<?php
$search=get_search_query();
$all_categories = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'category','hide_empty' => true) ); 
$all_tags = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag','hide_empty' => true) );
//if you have any custom taxonomy
$all_custom_taxonomy = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-slug','hide_empty' => true) );

$mcat=array();
$mtag=array();
$mcustom_taxonomy=array();

foreach($all_categories as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mcat,$all->term_id);
}
}

foreach($all_tags as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mtag,$all->term_id);
}
}

foreach($all_custom_taxonomy as $all){
$par=$all->name;
if (strpos($par, $search) !== false) {
array_push($mcustom_taxonomy,$all->term_id);
}
}

$matched_posts=array();
$args1= array( 
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'field' => 'term_id',
'terms' => $mcat
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
'field' => 'term_id',
'terms' => $mtag
),
array(
'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
'field' => 'term_id',
'terms' => $mcustom_taxonomy
)
)
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
array_push($matched_posts,get_the_id());
//echo '<li>' . get_the_id() . '</li>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}

?>
<?php
// now we will do the normal wordpress search
$query2 = new WP_Query( array( 's' => $search,'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
$query2->the_post();
array_push($matched_posts,get_the_id());
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}
$matched_posts= array_unique($matched_posts);
$matched_posts=array_values(array_filter($matched_posts));
//print_r($matched_posts);
?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query3 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'any','post__in' => $matched_posts ,'paged' => $paged) );
if ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
while ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
$query3->the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'excerpt' );
}
twentynineteen_the_posts_navigation();
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {

}
?>
```